# "the US." or "the US"

Tags: spelling

When I said

> "in my field, people earn triple in the US. for the same work in China."

a native speaker told me I should have got rid of that ".", is it a more modern style to refer to America?

[image]

Comment: If you used the full stop (period) because it's an abbreviation, you should have put one after both letters (U.S.) However, it's not necessary to use them at all; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_stop#After_initials (scroll down to _Acronyms and initialisms_).

Comment: Nitpick: Referring to the US as America is like referring to China as "Asia" ;)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

"US." is wrong.

**Initialisms** are either written with full-stops (periods) between *every* letter **or** *not at all*:

- The U.S.A.
- The USA

**Shortenings** are are abbreviations in which the end of the word has been dropped. These are written with *one* full stop at the end:

- Approx. (approximately)
- Esp. (especially)

I can see why you would think "the US" is an abbreviation (of "USA"), but really it is an initialism in its own right. As such, it should either have a full-stop after *every* letter, or *none*:

> The US
>   **or**
>   The U.S.

Note [this article](https://www.military.com/us-military-coronavirus-response) about the US Military which uses both options for an initialism. The headline has NO marks ("The US Military") but the body of the article does use marks ("the U.S. Military").

Comment: Nitpick: USA is an *initialism*, not an *acronym*.

Comment: Also, U.S. is American English and US is British English. Same for U.K. and UK.